# how to bulkify below trigger to run the million of records

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger runwaynew on Schedule__c (before insert, before update) {

 for ( Schedule__c sch : trigger.new){
    if (sch.Runway__c != NULL)  {
        List<Schedule__c> scc = [Select Id From Schedule__c  WHERE  Runway__c  = :sch.Runway__c  and  Date__c = :sch.Date__c];

    if (scc.size() > 0) {
        sch.addError('Flight Already Scheduled on the Runway');
     }
  }

 }
}
```

can you suggest me how to write test class on it...

Comment: Did you understand my answer ?

Answer (score 18):

Never mind asking for a test class, lets start with your trigger itself.

```
for ( Schedule__c sch : trigger.new){
    if (sch.Runway__c != NULL)  {
        List<Schedule__c> scc = [Select Id From Schedule__c  WHERE  Runway__c  = :sch.Runway__c  and  Date__c = :sch.Date__c];
```

**Never Ever Ever put a database action (query or dml) inside an iteration.** This would make so many separate calls to the database it would slow your code down tremendously, and require a lot more resources than required. This is why salesforce simply forces us to not do this with governor limits.

I am not gonna write the trigger for you, I want you to learn how to do that. So i'll explain how you can, or at least the way i would do it. Others may have different approaches.

- you are comparing any new or updated Schedule with all excisting Schedules to not allow a duplicate.
- as a workflow may still update your fields, i think this type of validation is better fitted for an after-update/insert trigger
- You would start by iterating(looping) all your new records and collect their Runway and Date fields in 2 lists (lets say `List<Runway__c> Runways` and `List<Date__c> SchedulesDates`)
- **After** your loop, you can query (once!) all Schedules where the Runway or Date is in either of the 2 lists.
- You will want to limit your schedule_*c query to schedules where the date*_c is in the future. I'm gonna assume you never schedule something in the past anyway.
- You now will want to cross match every of your new records with your results, for that you need to organise your queried possible (!) matches  in a way they are easily searchable. I propose `Map<Runway__c,Map<Date__c,Schedule__C>> SchedulesMappedByRunWayAndDate`.
- Now you loop over all your queried Schedules and add them to the map accordingly, if a 'subMap' for the specific Runway does not exist in SchedulesMappedByRunWayAndDate yet, you'll need to make it. For a given Runway, each date should be unique, I am expecting your data to be clean and this to be the case.
- Now you can get to what you want to do, you can iterate over all your new inserted/updated Schedules, and look if a record already exist for their Runway (most likely=yes). If that is the case, you can look in the submap if a schedule already exists for the given Date. If this is the case, you can perform the `addError(..)`; as in your code.
- Additionally: `sch.Runway__c != NULL`  You may want a validation rule to require a Runway to be selected, else that has to be in your code indeed.

(Additionally: Not to be rude, but I hope this is an exercise and you're not really making software for airports to organise their runway schedules and flights )

Comment: Excellent answer.  Wish I could vote more than once.  "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."